# ¿Crear clase para cifrado y descifrado simétrico de archivo de texto guardado en ruta local y lee archivo de texto cifrado en memoria?

Tags: c#, cifrado

Saludos he estado viendo pero al final necesito su ayuda. Porfavor para llegar a lo que necesito que es leer el archivo de texto cifrado y pasarlo de una variable a otro para comprobar que el texto cifrado dentro sea el mismo siendo descifrado sin guardarlo.

**Mi Objetivo:** Es leer el archivo cifrado con la clase INI en memoria he imprimir en MessageBox:

**Estoy teniendo problema con "Boton Leer Valor Encriptado" al leer el archivo cifrado con la clase INI una vez cifrado y descifrar sin guardar de manera local con ReadEncryptedFile no me muestra el valor.**

Me pueden ayudar en que me equivoco porfavor.

//**Clase FileInI:**

```
public class FileInI
{

    [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)] private static extern int WritePrivateProfileString(string pSection, string pKey, string pValue, string pFile);
    [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)] private static extern int WritePrivateProfileStruct(string pSection, string pKey, string pValue, int pValueLen, string pFile);
    [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)] private static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(string pSection, string pKey, string pDefault, byte[] prReturn, int pBufferLen, string pFile);
    [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)] private static extern int GetPrivateProfileStruct(string pSection, string pKey, byte[] prReturn, int pBufferLen, string pFile);

    private int li_BufferLen = 256;

    /// <summary>
    /// INIClass Constructor
    /// </summary>
    public FileInI(string pIniFilename){
        IniFile = pIniFilename;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// INI filename (If no path is specifyed the function will look with-in the windows directory for the file)
    /// </summary>
    public string IniFile { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Max return length when reading data (Max: 32767)
    /// </summary>
    public int BufferLen
    {
        get { return li_BufferLen; }
        set
        {
            if (value > 32767) { li_BufferLen = 32767; }
            else if (value < 1) { li_BufferLen = 1; }
            else { li_BufferLen = value; }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Read value from INI File
    /// </summary>
    public string ReadValue(string pSection, string pKey, string pDefault)
    {
        return z_GetString(pSection, pKey, pDefault);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Read value from INI File, default = ""
    /// </summary>
    public string ReadValue(string pSection, string pKey)
    {
        return z_GetString(pSection, pKey, "");
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Write value to INI File
    /// </summary>
    public void WriteValue(string pSection, string pKey, string pValue)
    {
        WritePrivateProfileString(pSection, pKey, pValue, this.IniFile);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Remove value from INI File
    /// </summary>
    public void RemoveValue(string pSection, string pKey)
    {

        WritePrivateProfileString(pSection, pKey, null, this.IniFile);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Read values in a section from INI File
    /// </summary>
    public void ReadValues(string pSection, ref Array pValues)
    {
        pValues = z_GetString(pSection, null, null).Split((char)0);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Read sections from INI File
    /// </summary>
    public void ReadSections(ref Array pSections)
    {
        pSections = z_GetString(null, null, null).Split((char)0);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Remove section from INI File
    /// </summary>
    public void RemoveSection(string pSection)
    {

        _ = WritePrivateProfileString(pSection, null, null, this.IniFile);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Call GetPrivateProfileString / GetPrivateProfileStruct API
    /// </summary>
    private string z_GetString(string pSection, string pKey, string pDefault)
    {

        string sRet = pDefault; byte[] bRet = new byte[li_BufferLen];
        int i = GetPrivateProfileString(pSection, pKey, pDefault, bRet, li_BufferLen, IniFile);
        sRet = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(bRet, 0, i).TrimEnd((char)0);
        return (sRet);
    }
}
```

//**Clase SymmetricTextFileEncryption:**

```
public class SymmetricTextFileEncryption
{
    private readonly string _key;
    private readonly string _iv;

    public SymmetricTextFileEncryption(string key, string iv)
    {
        _key = key;
        _iv = iv;
    }

    public void EncryptFile(string inputFile, string outputFile)
    {
        using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
        {
            aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_key);
            aes.IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_iv);

            using (var encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV))
            {
                using (var inputFileStream = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    using (var outputFileStream = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                    {
                        using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(outputFileStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                        {
                            inputFileStream.CopyTo(cryptoStream);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void DecryptFile(string inputFile, string outputFile)
    {
        using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
        {
            aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_key);
            aes.IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_iv);

            using (ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV))
            {
                using (FileStream inputFileStream = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    using (FileStream outputFileStream = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                    {
                        using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(inputFileStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                        {
                            cryptoStream.CopyTo(outputFileStream);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public string ReadEncryptedFile(string inputFile)
    {
        using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
        {
            aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_key);
            aes.IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_iv);

            using (ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV))
            {
                using (FileStream inputFileStream = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(inputFileStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(cryptoStream))
                        {
                            return reader.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

//**variables**

```
    string key = "ncfSJy7yV366y1EW";
    string iv = "ncfSJy7yV366y1EW";

    string inputFile = @".\File.ini";
    string encryptedFile = @".\File.encryp";
    string decryptedFile = @".\File.decryp";
```

//**Boton Leer Valor Encriptado:** leer el archivo de texto cifrado en memroria sin guardar de manera local y imprimir en MessageBox.

```
    private void Btn_Leer_Encrip_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SymmetricTextFileEncryption encryptor = new SymmetricTextFileEncryption(key, iv);

        string contenidotext = encryptor.ReadEncryptedFile(@".\File.encryp"); //Lee archivo encriptado guarda en memoria

        FileInI MyInIFile = new FileInI(contenidotext); //--Leer archivo ini con el encriptado en memoria 

        string leeINIValorShow = MyInIFile.ReadValue("Seccion", "Valor", ""); //--Leer valor del ini
        MessageBox.Show($"{"Leer valor encriptado: "}\n\n{leeINIValorShow}", "Alerta", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning); //--Pero esto no me imprime el valor
        //MessageBox.Show(leeINIShow.ToString());

        //**NOTA:** la clase INI Me lo lee el valor normal sin cifrar. Pero al leerlo cifrado no me muestra el valor.
    }
```

//**Boton Leer Valor Desencriptado:** leer el valor del archivo de texto he imprimir en MessageBox.

```
    private void Btn_Leer_Desencrip_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FileInI MyFileInI = new FileInI(inputFile);

        string leeINIValorShow = MyFileInI.ReadValue("Seccion", "Valor", "");
        MessageBox.Show($"{"Leer valor sin encriptado: "}{leeINIValorShow}", "Alerta", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
    }
```

//**Boton encrypt a file**

```
    private void Btn_Encriptacion_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SymmetricTextFileEncryption encryptor = new SymmetricTextFileEncryption(key, iv);
        try
        {
            encryptor.EncryptFile(inputFile, encryptedFile);
            MessageBox.Show("encrypt a file");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

//**Boton decrypt a file**

```
    private void Btn_Desencriptacion_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SymmetricTextFileEncryption encryptor = new SymmetricTextFileEncryption(key, iv);
        try
        {
            encryptor.DecryptFile(encryptedFile, decryptedFile);
            MessageBox.Show("decrypt a file");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Cual es el error especificamene? "dices que tienes en ReadEncryptedFile", pero seria bueno si puedes indicar el mensaje o lo que hiciste hasta el momento

Comment: Estuve viendolo mas pero no practicamente un error solo que no me muestra los datos de ReadEncryptedFile a MyInI, pero si imprimo ReadEncryptedFile con un MessageBox me lee el archivo cifrado correctamente pero pasarlo a MyInI no pasa los datos.

Comment: Francamente no se entiende lo que buscas

Comment: leer el archivo cifrado en memoria como se muestra y con la clase INI que esta leer el valor y pasarlo o imprimir lo en MessageBox.Show(leeValorINI);

Editare la pregunta mira nuevamente porfa.

Comment: Para no complicarte, no puedes usar algo como [esto](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3683911/how-to-use-symmetric-and-asymmetric-encryption-in-c-sharp.html)?

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que cuando desencriptas inicializas la clase metiéndole el contenido desencriptado, no el nombre del fichero. El comando que utilizas en z_string no acepta pasarle el fichero en memoria.
Tienes dos opciones que haya encontrado, ya que no encontré un comando para leer inis en memoria buscándolo, son las siguientes:

1. Fabricarte un buscador para estos casos,por ejemplo:

   ```
   private string g_GetString(string pSection, string pKey)
        {
            string[] list;
            if (pKey == "")//no hay clave a buscar
                return "";
            if (pSection == "")//no hay secciones
                list = IniFile.Split('\n');
            else
            {

                int a = IniFile.IndexOf(pSection); //encuentra el index de la seccion
                if (a == -1)
                    return "";

                int fiseccion = IniFile.IndexOf("[", a + 1);
                string seccion;
                if (fiseccion == -1) //ultima seccion
                    seccion = IniFile.Substring(a);

                else
                    seccion = IniFile.Substring(a, fiseccion);
                list = seccion.Split('\n');
            }





            return list.Where(item => item.Contains(pKey)).First().Split('=')[1].Trim((char)0);
        }
   ```
2. Guardarte el texto desencriptado en un fichero y usar el path del fichero